# Table Of Contents won't show subsites and pages at the same level

Tags: web-part

I am using the Table Of Contents webpart, but I cannot get it to show the contents in a logical manner. The problem is that pages and subsites are treated differently in the displayed hierarchy.

I want to show subsites and pages at the first level. These are the settings I have tried:

```
Levels: 1
Show content from starting location: False
Show pages
```

This shows subsites at the first level, but not pages at first level. However, pages at the 2nd level are shown.

```
Levels: 2
Show content from starting location: False
Show pages
```

This shows subsites at 1st and 2nd level, as well as pages at 2nd and 3rd level. However, pages at 1st level are not shown.

```
Levels 2:
Show content from starting location: True
Show pages
```

This shows subsites and pages at 1st level. It also shows pages at 2nd level, but not subsites at 2nd level.